# How to set background color of a button as the THREE js textGeometry color?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to set the background color of a button to a THREE JS textGeometry color.

```
 var element = event.target;
 var hexColor = $(element).css("background-color");
```

> Here the onclick of the button is saved and its background is stored in the hexColor variable.

```
var parse = hexColor.toLowerCase().match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+) 
            (?:,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?\)$/);
var rgbColor = {
            r : parseInt(parse[1]),
            g : parseInt(parse[2]),
            b : parseInt(parse[3])
};
activeElement.material.color = rgbColor;
```

> The output of the parse is an array of size 6 with r,g,b values as strings.After that, I parse the corresponding values to integer and save as an object.When I set the object as the material color of the active textGeometry element, It will become white...No other colors are visible.Is this the correct method?

Comment: Try `activeElement.material.color.set(hexColor);` (r91)

Comment: Thank you @prisoner849..It's working!!!